# What will be the new query this I was using in old version for search 7.17 now for 8.7 Elasticsearch with NODEJS

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-8

What will be the new query this I was using in old version for search 7.17:

```
const { body } = await Client.search({
  index: this.tableName,
  body: {
    sort: sortingData,
    from: skip,
    size: limit,
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: mustData,
      }
    }
  }
});
```